# How to create point scoring system in processing with circles?

Tags: processing

So the goal is add a black circle every time the hammer or the bucket drops without hitting the person and then add 4 circles every time the person goes inside the door, when the first line of circles is filled it will go onto the second line until the entire screen is filled and then it resets. Also with the person is hit by either the hammer or the bucket a whole row of of red circle will appear. I'm not sure how to go about doing it, thanks.

```
// all the variables I need for two tools
int hammerPos = 0; 
int hammerVel = 1; 
int hammerPending = 0;
int bucketPos = 0; 
int bucketVel = 2; 
int bucketPending = 0;

int mrPos;
int jump = 60;
boolean doorOpen = true;

long timeAt;    // the time at which the door was last opened or closed
long waitTime; // the time to wait (in total) until the door opens next

void setup() {
  size(512, 348);
  mrPos = width/8;
  frameRate(30);
  waitTime = int(random(3000, 8000));
}

void draw() {
  if (millis() > timeAt + waitTime) {  // calculation will tell me if current time (millis) has gone past the last time the door opened plus waitTime
    doorOpen = !doorOpen;
    timeAt = millis();                // reset last opening time to now
    waitTime = int(random(3000, 8000));// choose new waiting time
  }

  background(159, 172, 173);
  rectMode(CORNERS);
  ellipseMode(CORNERS);
  noStroke();

  house();
  mrg();
  hazard();
  score();
}

void hazard() { 
  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(6);
  line(128, hammerPos+10, 148, hammerPos-12);
  strokeWeight(4);
  line(125, hammerPos+13, 129, hammerPos+11);
  strokeWeight(8);
  line(115, hammerPos+5, 130, hammerPos+20);

  // draw bucket
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  triangle(167, bucketPos-5, 187, bucketPos-12, 188, bucketPos+12);
  triangle(167, bucketPos-5, 187, bucketPos+12, 169, bucketPos+14);
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  ellipse(183, bucketPos-11, 195, bucketPos+10);

  if (bucketPos >height) {
    bucketPos=0;
  }

  if (hammerPos>height) {
    hammerPos=0;
  }


  if (hammerPos > 240 && hammerPos < 300 && mrPos == width/4) {
    mrPos = width/8;
  }
  if (bucketPos > 240 && bucketPos < 300 && mrPos == 3*width/8) {
    mrPos = width/8;
  }


  // animate all automatically moving objects.. first update pending then decide if there is a jump this frame
  hammerPending = hammerPending + hammerVel;
  bucketPending = bucketPending + bucketVel;
  if (hammerPending > jump) {
    hammerPos = hammerPos + hammerPending;
    hammerPending = 0;
  }
  if (bucketPending > jump) {
    bucketPos = bucketPos + bucketPending;
    bucketPending = 0;
  }
}


void score() {
  if (hammerPos>height) {
    ellipse(40, 40, 40, 40);
  }
}




//draw house
void house() {
  strokeWeight(20);
  stroke(0);
  line(402, 206, 490, 169);
  line(490, 169, 512, 179);
  strokeWeight(2);
  noFill();
  line(411, 213, 411, 305);
  rect(419, 210, 468, 295);

  if (doorOpen) {
    line(479, 206, 499, 199);
    line(499, 199, 499, 314);
    line(499, 314, 478, 302);
    fill(0);
    noStroke();
    triangle(476, 225, 493, 219, 493, 243);
    triangle(476, 225, 493, 243, 476, 240);

    ellipse(487, 255, 493, 263);
    arc(499, 255, 507, 262, 3*HALF_PI, HALF_PI, CHORD);
  } else {
    fill(0);
    noStroke();
    rect(432, 225, 453, 243, 2);
    ellipse(425, 255, 431, 263);
  }
}



// draw MrGW
void mrg() {
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(mrPos-13, 232, mrPos+17, 263);
  fill(159, 172, 173);
  ellipse(mrPos+3, 250, mrPos+17, 260);
  fill(0);
  triangle(mrPos+2, 258, mrPos-11, 278, mrPos+1, 285);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == RIGHT && (mrPos < 7*(width/8)) && doorOpen) { // mr gw is moving right and the door is open
    mrPos = mrPos + width/8;
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT && (mrPos < 6*(width/8))) {      // mr gw is moving right not including last slot
    mrPos = mrPos + width/8;
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT && (mrPos > width/8)) {           // mr gw is moving left.
    mrPos = mrPos - width/8;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need a variable for the number of points/circles: `points`. The circles itself should be drawn in the void loop, maybe with two for loops (see below).

Additionally, you will need to define, which of the circles should be red. In the following example I use a boolean Array, that defines for each circle if it should be red. So if the first circle has to be red, you have to set `redPoint[0]` to `true`...

```
int i=0;
for(int y=10; y<height-10; y+=20) {
  for(int x=10; x<width-10; x+=20) {
    if(redPoint[i] == true) {
      fill(255,0,0);
    } else {
      fill(0);
    }
    if(i<points) {
      ellipse(x,y,15,15);
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```